# Extract text from epub in Python

Tags: python, nltk, text-mining, epub

I have written following code to extract the words of a ebook and add them to a corpus for text-mining purposes.

```
# loading the german corpus
from ebooklib import epub
import ebooklib
import os
import nltk
input_path = r"C:\Users\jzeh\Desktop\Directory"
german_corpus = []
book = epub.read_epub(os.path.join(input_path,'grimms-maerchen.epub'))
for doc in book.get_items():
    german_corpus += str(doc.content)
    german_corpus = [w.lower() for w in nltk.word_tokenize(german_corpus)]
```

Unfortunately running the code gives me the error:

```
TypeError  ---> 12     german_corpus = [w.lower() for w in nltk.word_tokenize(german_corpus)]
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Could anyone tell me, what I am missing?

Comment: Even if you might figured it our yourself: This won't work since you will extract every type of content from the epub. This will not only be words but also html and xml tags which will mess up your corpus. Furthermore, think about using a lemmatizer first to normalize your vocabulary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nltk.word_tokenize` takes a string as an input, you have passed it a list. If I understand correctly, I think you want this:

```
...

for doc in book.get_items():
    doc_content = str(doc.content)
    for w in nltk.word_tokenize(doc_content):
        german_corpus.append(w.lower())
```